# How to type a return value to be an array of the same size as the number of variadic inputs

Tags: typescript

I want to create a `useTranslations` function which can take as input a number of keys to be translated, and I want the return type to denote that the same number of translations will be returned as requested.

```
export function useTranslations(...keys: string[]): ??? {
  return keys.map(k => translate(k));
}
```

If I use `string[]` as the return type, someone could destructure it with the incorrect number of outputs.

Comment: Why not use a generic type, given the argument and return types will be the same, so if the user passes a tuple rather than array type it gets passed through?

Comment: What does the `translate` function do and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using TypeScript tuple types to specify the exact number and types of translations that will be returned based on the number of keys passed as arguments.

You just define generic type that extends from array of strings (your keys) and return `{ [K in keyof T]: string }`, that is actually an array of strings with the same length as the number of keys passed in,

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgEsD2qA8MUEAHsBEgCYpQrBxZIDmA2gLoB8UAvFAN4BYAFBQoLANJRGUANYQQOAGaw2ALlr1GTANzCAvrqHCAxnjpR6ydJmi8AFMHV0GzAJQ8uwQ8NJgccYChFAFckY2w8KGCUCHgrDAiCIlJyKhpnLXYOOwA6PLkQFHUYV3U+MUlpAqUVJ01mKD1+YVE4CGBguCRZeRQcgFsEMDsZDwtEVASIEdd3BBo4ycxcJI5DPWETM0DLJcSaXmjYiet9uwAiAoBGc4AaKEv5ACY7h4KAZleAcgKAFi-XNogA)

```js
type Translations<T extends string[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string;
};

const translate = (t: string) => t;

export function useTranslations<T extends string[]>(...keys: T): Translations<T> {
  return keys.map(k => translate(k)) as Translations<T>;
}

const translations = useTranslations("key1", "key2", "key3", 'key4');
```

Answer (score 0):

To me `useTranslations` looks like a [React Hook](https://react.dev/reference/react#state-hooks) that you probably want to use something like:

```
const [translation1, translation2] = useTranslations("key1", "key2");
```

You could work with [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) to asure the number of key arguments and the length of the returned array (tuple) match.

```
declare function translate(key: string): unknown;

export function useTranslations<T extends string[]>(...keys: T): T {
  return keys.map(k => translate(k)) as any;
}

const [t1, t2, t3] = useTranslations("key1", "key2");
//             ~~
// Tuple type '[string, string]' of length '2' has no element at index '2''
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxilQGdoMQAKAaxAE8AueEwrVAcwEom1rUcA7qgDcAKFEgAHgAccMDEjSZc+ZCRAAVIqXIqSAHg3wpFVMBLNWHANoBdAHyUAdC9p0STDd3hGA3qPh4OAxkGHw3EicAWyhpGngAXnsCbTIoChpOTngoC2I6MQBfcTA8FnhrDABGABoCACY6jABmW0T4NU1U3TLKACI3Kr66gfp6vs4xAHopwLn5+YA-RdEZn2RpCAQMOmkEAHJrFhg2djrj09t9+BxEeC2ODAALeH3666fc+H5jLaiQVAKdLwNigSSvd5AA)